# Can we add event bridge trigger to step function, like we do for aws lambda, so that step function triggers when we push an event to the bus

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-step-functions, aws-serverless

I am trying to trigger step function once an event with matching pattern(source) is pushed to event bus. Can we attach the event bridge trigger to step function, like we do for lambda, so that the step function triggers when we push an event to the bus using serverless framework. I tried adding the same eventbridge configs to both lambda and SF, lambda is triggering but step function won't.

Here's the yml block for lambda function

```
lambdaName:
  handler: handlers/lambdaName.handler
  events:
  - eventBridge:
     name: subscriber-handler
     eventBus: arn:aws:events:region:account:event-bus/trigger-stepfunction
     pattern:
        source:
          - 'test-SF-trigger'
```

Here's the yml block for Step function:

```
stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    XyzStateMachine:
      name: xyz-state-machine-name
      id: xyz-state-machine-id
      events:
        - eventBridge:
           name: subscriber-handler
           eventBus: arn:aws:events:region:account:event-bus/trigger-stepfunction
           pattern:
              source:
                - 'test-SF-trigger'
      definition:
        Comment: "AWS Step Functions state machine to fetch data from DB day wise, write it to file and send to DL"
        StartAt: "state1"
        States:
          state1:
            Type: "Task"
            Resource: 
              Fn::GetAtt: [XYZ_lambda, Arn]
            Next: 'state2' .........
```

For the above case, I am able to trigger lambda when i push an event with matching source to that even bus but not able to trigger step function. Can we do like this for triggering stepfunction also, if yes please let me know what I am missing?

Edit1: Also, let me know if we can not attach custom events like this for SF?

Note: I am able to trigger SF by creating a cloudformation bus and rule and configuring step function in target of that rule. Please let me know if we can setup AWS Step Functions to react to events coming in via the EventBridge, like above.

Comment: you could do an eventBridge + Lambda -> Start StateMachine. Basically when an event matching a particular pattern is dropped on the Bus trigger the lambda. The lambda can have code to trigger the step-function via api calls.

Comment: okay, so we can not setup stepFunctions to react to eventbridge custom events directly?

Comment: yes. based on available documentation . it only supports Rule based trigger or api calls.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is no need for an intermediate lambda. It looks like your example differs from the structure in the state machine plugin documentation.

https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-step-functions

also , make sure the iam perms for your bus/rule/sfn are configured correctly

```yaml
stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    exampleCloudwatchEventStartsMachine:
      events:
        - cloudwatchEvent:
            eventBusName: 'my-custom-event-bus'
            event:
              source:
                - "my.custom.source"
              detail-type:
                - "My Event Type"
              detail:
                state:
                  - pending
      definition:
        ...
```